# Get the Schema title of an Embedded Schema within a Razor template?

Tags: templating, razormediator

**Edit following request for clarity:**
I wanted to know if it were possible to get the Schema of an embedded field directly using the razor mediator.  As the answers below state, it isn't.

---

**Original Question:**
Is it possible  to get the schema title of an embedded schema within a razor template?

I have this razor template which is looping over a repeatable embedded schema.

```cs
@foreach(dynamic comp in Component.Fields.links)
{
    {
        <p>@comp.Schema.Title</p>
    } 
}
```

`@comp.Schema.Title` is giving the following error in template builder:

> **DynamicItemFields: Key 'schema' Not Found In ItemFields**

Comment: 'comp' is not a component but a field inside this loop which makes the question slightly misleading imo...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You won't be able to get the embedded schema directly with the Razor Mediator, but since its just a wrapper of the TOM.NET API, you can create your own function that returns the schema's title.

The following example allows you to pass it a ComponentModel instance and a name of the field that you want to get the embedded schema's title for:

```cs
@using Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Fields

@functions {
    public string GetEmbeddedSchemaTitle(Models.ComponentModel component, string fieldName) {
        ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(component.TridionObject.Content, component.Schema);
        EmbeddedSchemaField embeddedField = fields[fieldName] as EmbeddedSchemaField;
        if (embeddedField != null) {
            return ((EmbeddedSchemaFieldDefinition)embeddedField.Definition)
                .EmbeddedSchema.Title;
        }
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Then, for you first example, you could do the following (assuming your field "link" is a multi-valued component link field, and the field name using an embedded schema for each of these components is "MyEmbeddedField"):

```cs
@foreach (dynamic comp in Component.Fields.link) {
    <div>Title For "MyEmbeddedField": @GetEmbeddedSchemaTitle(comp, "MyEmbeddedField")</div>
}
```

**Update w/ New Assumption**

Looking at the error message you provided, the above use example's assumptions are probably incorrect.  It looks like your "link" field is a multi-valued embedded schema field, in which case a use example for that would be:

```cs
GetEmbeddedSchemaTitle(Component, "link")
```

Notice that you are not passing your "comp" variable in, but the actual "Component" variable for the assumption that Component contains an embedded schema field named "link".

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Component's XML you will find no trace of this embedded schema, as Tridion *embeds* it in the owning component.

The XML will look +/- like this:

```
<Content>
    <Field>value</Field>
    <EmbeddedField>
        <Field>Value</Field>
    </EmbeddedField>
</Content>
```

There's no property in the component itself indicating that this contains an embedded schema. I don't know about Razor, my impression is that you can use the full TOM.NET from it anyway. With TOM.NET you could do something like this:

```cs
ItemFields fields = new ItemFields(Component.Content, Component.Schema);
EmbeddedSchemaField embedded = (EmbeddedSchemaField)fields["EmbeddedField"];
Schema schema = embedded.Definition.EmbeddedSchema;
```